# Application.Volatile help - Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-udf

I am working on building a budget file in Excel:

- in row 2 I have the months
- in Column A I have my budget types (categories).

Rather than build a bunch of sumifs in each individual cell, I'm trying to write a custom VBA function for each input (bank, AMEX, VISA etc).

The problem I am running into - without `Application.Volatile` code, the values do not update automatically in each cell after editing other cells - but when I add `Application.Volatile` in, it simply records the last value in EVERY CELL, ignoring the budget type (category).

Any ideas how I can build this function?

```
Function AMEX() As Double
    Application.Volatile
    Dim rngNet As Range
    Dim rngMonth As Range
    Dim rngTypes As Range
    Dim intSearchMonth As Integer
    Dim strSearchType As String

    Set rngNet = shAMEX.Range("E:E")
    Set rngMonth = shAMEX.Range("F:F")
    Set rngTypes = shAMEX.Range("G:G")
    intSearchMonth = shBudget.Cells(2, ActiveCell.Column)
    strSearchType = shBudget.Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 1)

    AMEX = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(rngNet, _
                                                rngMonth, intSearchMonth, _
                                                rngTypes, strSearchType)
End Function
```

Comment: (a) Don't ever use `ActiveCell` in a UDF.  Use `Application.Caller` instead.  (That refers to the cell calling the function.)  (b) Why don't you pass your ranges and cells to the function as parameters.  Then you won't have to mark it `Volatile` and won't slow down your spreadsheet so much.

Comment: Thanks @YowE3K! Sometimes the solution is so simple/obvious you miss it! That would work perfectly.

Also thank you for the tip on `Application.Caller`